# Bake particle system animation and delete few particles

Tags: particles

I want to delete few particles from particle system. After baking the animation still I cant select particle objects, it selects all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I know to edit already emitted particle objects would be to *Make Duplicates Real* <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> accessible in *Object Menu* after that you could select the mesh and invoke *Separate by loose parts* in *Edit Mode* <kbd>P</kbd>. This wouldn't help on animations.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't it help for animations?

Comment: @TimTimmy because converting the particle system to a mesh will only 'capture' the particles of a single frame.